Generating the authentication token Using OAuth 2.0 for calling Google developer API from .NET MAUI Mobile Application
I am trying to generate the authentication token using OAuth 2.0 for the .NET MAUI Mobile Application using the Google Cloud Console project to call the Google Developer API. For that, I created the project on the Google Cloud console, enabled the Google developer API and configured the consent screen with an external app type, created the OAuth 2.0 client ID with application type Android, and added the package name and SHA-1 fingerprint. I installed the NuGet packages below for the MAUI project.

Microsoft.Identity.Client
System.Net.Http.Json.

I added the below code to implement the OAuth flow on the MAUI Project.
        public class GoogleAuthService
        {
            private readonly IPublicClientApplication _pca;

            public GoogleAuthService()
            {
                _pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create("OAuth 2.0 client ID")
                    .WithRedirectUri("com.googleusercontent.apps.OAuth 2.0 client ID:/oauth2redirect")
                    .Build();
            }
            public async Task<string> AuthenticateAsync()
            {
                try
                {
                    // Scopes for accessing Google APIs
                    string[] scopes = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher" };

                    var result = await _pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                        .WithParentActivityOrWindow(MainActivity.CurrentActivity)
                        .ExecuteAsync();

                    Console.WriteLine($"GoogleAPIAccessToken: {result.AccessToken}");
                    return result.AccessToken; // Use this access token for API calls
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Handle authentication errors
                    Console.WriteLine($"Authentication failed: {ex.Message}");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

On MainActivity.cs:
public static MainActivity CurrentActivity { get; private set; }


protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CurrentActivity = this;
    Instance = this;
}


protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

On AndroidManifest.xml:
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="com.googleusercontent.apps.OAuth 2.0 client ID" />
        <data android:host="oauth2redirect" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

To generate the access token from the below function, I call the GoogleAuthService();
private readonly GoogleAuthService _googleAuthService;

_googleAuthService = new GoogleAuthService();


public async void LoginButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string token = await _googleAuthService.AuthenticateAsync();
}

If I click on LoginButton, It navigates to the Microsoft login page, and If I try to log in with mail, it shows the below error.


We're unable to complete your request
unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.


Screenshot:

Update:
I tried another way to implement OAuth flow on the MAUI Project. While creating the OAuth 2.0 client ID, we can download the OAuth credentials as a JSON file (client_secrets.json). I added this JSON file to the MAUI project under the Platforms, Android folder. After adding the JSON file, I set the Build Action to Content and Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always from the properties of this JSON file. Then, I added the below functions.
public class GoogleAuthService
{
    private static readonly string[] Scopes = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher" };
    private const string ApplicationName = "AlertBuddies";

    public async Task<UserCredential> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        try
        {               
            using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("Platforms/Android/client_secret.json"))
            {
                var credPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "token.json");

                var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true));

                Console.WriteLine($"GoogleAPIAccessToken: {credential.Token.AccessToken}");
                return credential;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Authentication failed: {ex.Message}");
            return null;
        }
    }
}

On AndroidManifest.xml:
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="com.googleusercontent.apps.OAuth 2.0 client ID" />
        <data android:host="oauth2redirect" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

To generate the access token from the below function, I call the GoogleAuthService();
public async void LoginButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var credential = await _googleAuthService.AuthenticateAsync();
    if (credential != null)
    {
        var token = credential.Token.AccessToken;
    }
}

If I click on LoginButton, I get the below error or exception.


Authentication failed: Android/client_secret.json


So, I am unable to generate the authentication token using OAuth 2.0. Is this process correct? How can I generate the authentication token using OAuth 2.0 to call the Google Developer API from the .NET MAUI Mobile Application for subscription status fetch from the Google Play Store?
Please suggest a solution for this.
